# If $(A,B)$ is controllable, is $(A^\ast, B^\ast)$ too?

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}\,\, (n\geq m)$ and
$$ A^\ast = \begin{pmatrix} A & -aI \\ a I & A \end{pmatrix} \, , \quad B^\ast= \begin{pmatrix} B & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{pmatrix} \, ,$$
where $a>0$.

According to the [Popov-Belevitch-Hautus Eigenvector Test](https://books.google.de/books?id=UPWAmAXQu1AC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=left%20eigenvector%20controllability&source=bl&ots=BG7NwFtGB4&sig=ACfU3U17KlqNOBubHtB_FGPiqj5YDBp0AQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiN9b_8nKLqAhWJDewKHUGvAkMQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=left%20eigenvector%20controllability&f=false), $(A,B)$ is [controllable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability) iff **no** left eigenvector $x^\top$ of $A$ is orthogonal to the columns of $B$:
$$ (A,B) \text{ controllable} \iff x^\top A = \lambda x^\top, \, x^\top B \neq 0 \, .$$

I would like to proof (and need some verification and/or guidance) that if $(A,B)$ is *controllable* and $A$ is *diagonalizable*, then $(A^\ast, B^\ast)$ is controllable.

My humble try of a proof:

Using the Kronecker product, we can write
$$A^\ast =  I_2 \otimes A + a \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \otimes I_n \, ,$$

where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of dimension $n$. Therefore we have for every left eigenvector $x^\top$ of $A$, two left eigenvectors of $A^\ast$, namely
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & \pm i \end{bmatrix} \otimes x^\top = \begin{bmatrix} x^\top & \pm i x^\top \end{bmatrix} \, . \quad (*)$$

Using the first assumption that $A$ is diagonalizable, all left eigenvectors of $A^\ast$ are of the form given in $(*)$. Employing the second assumption that $(A,B)$ is controllable, it follows that no left eigenvector of $A^\ast$ can be orthogonal to the columns of $B^\ast$ and so $(A^\ast, B^\ast)$ is controllable.

1. Is this a valid proof?
2. Any suggestions/improvements?
3. Are there stronger results?

Comment: I think this is a perfectly fine proof.